# Is there a closed formula for the expected value of the hazard function of the normal distribution?

Tags: calculus, integration, statistics, definite-integrals

Let $\phi \left( x\right) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}\text{,}$
and
$\Phi \left( x\right) =\int\limits_{-\infty }^{x}\phi \left( t\right) dt.$
For a probability related problem, I would need, if exists, a closed formula for the following expression:

> $$\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }\frac{\left(\phi \left( x\right)\right)^2 }{\Phi \left(
> x\right) }dx$$

I tried partial integration, but it didn't seem to give anything useful.

If the above is easy, I would also need a closed form for the following more general form:

> $$\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }\frac{\phi \left( x\right)\phi \left( kx\right) }{\Phi \left(
> kx\right) }dx$$

where $k$ is an arbitrary constant.

Comment: nope....nothing to win here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As tired commented, I do not think that any closed form could be found for
$$I_k=\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }\frac{\phi \left( x\right)\phi \left( kx\right) }{\Phi \left(
kx\right) }dx=\frac 1 \pi\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2} \left(k^2+1\right) x^2}}{1+  \text{erf}\left(\frac{k
   x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}\,dx$$ (even for $k=1$) and I am afraid that you need to use numerical integration.

Out of curioisity, I computed a few values given below
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 k & I_k & I_k -I_{k-1} \\
 0 & 0.797884567 & \\
 1 & 0.903197399 & 0.105312832 \\
 2 & 1.161881356 & 0.258683957 \\
 3 & 1.486110005 & 0.324228649 \\
 4 & 1.838489833 & 0.352379827 \\
 5 & 2.205275277 & 0.366785445 \\
 6 & 2.580474755 & 0.375199477 \\
 7 & 2.961056008 & 0.380581253 \\
 8 & 3.345310185 & 0.384254177 \\
 9 & 3.732195055 & 0.386884870 \\
 10 & 4.121035782 & 0.388840727 \\
 11 & 4.511374450 & 0.390338668 \\
 12 & 4.902888401 & 0.391513951 \\
 13 & 5.295343199 & 0.39245480 \\
 14 & 5.688564122 & 0.39322092 \\
 15 & 6.082418110 & 0.39385399 \\
 16 & 6.476801884 & 0.39438377 \\
 17 & 6.871633890 & 0.39483201 \\
 18 & 7.266848707 & 0.39521482 \\
 19 & 7.662483439 & 0.39563473 \\
 20 & 8.058333292 & 0.39584985
\end{array}
\right)$$
 What it seems is that for large values of $k$, $I_k$ is "almost" a linear function of $k$.